# Field Array in React using formik

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, formik

I wanted to follow like a todo list. Something just like in the picture below.
Right now, the problem with my code is that, its working differently.
I wanted only one input that renders a list of divs instead of input fields.
Exactly just like in the picture below:

[image]

Pls check my codesandbox here

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-field-array-hssrum?file=/src/App.js:324-1266)

```
     <FieldArray
        name="todos"
        render={(arrayHelpers) => (
          <div>
            {formik.values.todos.map((friend, index) => (
              <div key={index} style={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem" }}>
                <input
                  name={`todos[${index}].name`}
                  value={formik.values.todos[index].name}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                />
                <button
                  disabled={formik.values.todos?.length === 1}
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                  className="deleteButton"
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              </div>
            ))}
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({ name: "" })}
            >
              Add
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-field-array-forked-56lgko) a very simple and rude approach - I used Formik my project some time ago and I'm pretty sure it's not perfect but this is exactly what you need.

So some details.

- do not render input for every item in your list, you need only render it's value and element with delete handler
- you need only one controlled input and it's value is used for `name` field in your `todos`. State is cleaned when you click `Add` button.
- you need to render your element only if `formik.values.todos.lenght > 0`
- you need to disable `Delete` button when `formik.values.todos.lenght === 1`
- `Add` button should be disabled when `newValue.lenght === 0`

Piece a cake, right?